# How can I run rtorrent headless on OSX?

Tags: macos, rtorrent

Ideally, I'm looking for a launchd script that will start rtorrent headless as a user daemon, along with the minimal set of configurations that will allow it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `rtorrent` client uses ncurses to display de UI, so you would need something like `screen` from GNU in order start it in background. This way, `screen` can stay as a headless daemon keeping `rtorrent` working. Look for more info about `screen`"detached mode".

If you google about the same topic but for Linux, you will find plenty of information in this technique.